# Find specific xpath when using jaxws

Tags: java, xml, xpath, wsdl, jax-ws

We use jaxws to convert WSDLs into java objects.  Is there a map from xpath to java object readily available using jaxws?

In example, suppose I'm interested in the information in `/some/x/path`, what is the quickest way to find the java object that holds that information?

I'm new to jaxws and WSDLs so feel free to let your answers be as verbose as possible :-D

Comment: There is no way to do this except unreliable hacks and hard-coded workarounds.  Perhaps we can help more if you explain why you need this?

Comment: Well a basic task would be.  The WSDL is changing and now /this/x/path is coming and we need to ingest it.  Its not incredibly challenging to figure what what object leads to /this/x/path but I feel like it should be trivial since the objects are generated from the WSDL.